# Template argument deduction with designated initializers

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following peace of example code:

```
#include <array>
template<std::size_t N>
struct Cfg {
  std::array<int, N> Values;
  // ... more fields
}

constexpr Cfg c = {
  .Values = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

Is it possible to deduce the template parameter N from the designated initializers? Using makeArray or initialize it with a defined array doesn't work either. Doing Cfg<4> for example works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designated initializer is not relevant here. For the purpose of class template argument deduction it is just handled as if it was a usual element of the initializer list.

(At least that is how I read the standard. It is a bit unclear in [[over.match.class.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.class.deduct#4) how a designated initializer ought to be handled when actually performing the overload resolution over the set of deduction guides.)

---

The problem is that there is no implicit deduction guide to deduce from the nested (untyped) braces, which can only deduce `std::initializer_list` and (reference to) array types, but your member is `std::array`. Or to be more precise the implicit aggregate deduction guide will not be formed under these circumstances.

Both

```
constexpr Cfg c = {
  .Values = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

and

```
constexpr Cfg c = {
  { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

will fail, but both

```
constexpr Cfg c = {
  .Values = std::array{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

and

```
constexpr Cfg c = {
  std::array{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

will work since you now gave the initializer a type that the implicit aggregate deduction guide (since C++20) can deduce against the `std::array` member.

---

To make the syntax without explicit `std::array` work you will need to add a deduction guide that can deduce the size of the nested braced-init list, for example:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
Cfg(const T(&)[N]) -> Cfg<N>;
```

MSVC and Clang do not accept this though, I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with C++17's [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

```cpp
#include <array>

template<std::size_t N>
struct Cfg {
    std::array<int, N> Values;
};

constexpr Cfg c {
    .Values = std::array { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
}; //         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Try it live.](https://godbolt.org/z/G5KcPenhn)

Comment: *psst* `c` is also subject, to ctad, so it's not like the OP needs a mention of ctad. How about explaining **why** you made the change you did, and OP's attempt failed?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm at a level where I cannot explain this with enough precision, while still instinctively knowing what the solution might be. I would've said that this is basically like trying to have two nested implicit conversions, and that by resolving the most nested one the compiler could then workout the topmost one. I'm glad someone beat me to it with a good explanation ahah